# C multiprocessing/pipes

Tags: c, pipe, multiprocessing

I'm just learning how fork() works in C.
The idea is to spawn 3 child processes that each send some info to the parent process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    int pid[3] = {0,0,0};
    int status = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    pipe(fd);

    pid[i] = fork();
    if (pid[i] < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pid[i] == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        char *arr = malloc(sizeof(char));
        sprintf(arr, "%i", i);
        write(fd[1], arr, 1);
        exit(0);
    }


}

for(int j=0; j < 3; j++)
{
    close(fd[1]);
    if (pid[j] > 0)
    {
        sleep(0);
        pid[j] = wait(&status);
        char *out = malloc(20 *sizeof(char));
        read(fd[0], out, 6);
        printf("%s\n", out);
        free(out);
        printf("I am the parent\n");

    }
}


}
```

The intended out put was:

```
1
I am the parent
2
I am the parent
3
I am the parent
```

The real output is:
    2
    I am the parent
    2
    I am the parent
    2
    I am the parent

Why is this happening?

Comment: Every time through your first `for` loop you call `pipe(fd)` and lose the descriptors for the pipe you created the last time around the loop. You need three pipes for three child processes, here, not one. You should be checking the return from *all* your system calls, not just `fork()` - `close(fd[1])` would have been shouting at you, if you had.

Comment: I thought that by calling pipe(fd) inside the loop I was creating 3 pipes. If this fails, then how do I make 3 pipes?

Comment: @user3614293 create a 3x2 array to hold 3 pairs of file descriptors, just like you did with the `pid`s.

Comment: You *are* creating three pipes, but you're only retaining a reference to the last one. You should do something like `int fd1[2], fd2[2], fd3[2]` (or `int fd[3][2]`) and call `pipe()` on each of them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
pipe(fd);
```

multiple times in the first `for` loop. Consider moving it before the loop, as it returns a new pair of file descriptors for reading/writing each time you call it.

Also, `close(fd[1])` should only be called once from the parent process.

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. You're calling `pipe(fd)` three times in your first `for` loop, and while you're creating three pipes, you're only saving a reference to one of them. Accordingly, in your second `for` loop, you're reading from the third pipe you create each time. You should have an array to store the references to all three of your pipes.
2. You should be checking the return from *all* of your system calls that can fail. Because of point 1 above, `close(fd[1])` would have been failing two times out of three if you'd done this, and it would have alerted you to the fact something was up. Checking the return from system calls is not just to guard against the possibility of unlikely errors, but also to help you debug, because the most likely reason for them failing is you doing something wrong, as was the case here.
3. There's absolutely no need to use `malloc()`, here - a regular `char` array is fine. Moreover, `malloc(sizeof(char));` allocates space for *one* character, when you need at least two (i.e. a single digit, and the terminating null character). Furthermore, you should always check the return from `malloc()` because it can fail. Also, `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition, so it's always superfluous.
4. To get your desired output, you should be adding `1` to `i`, since otherwise `i` will be `0`, then `1`, then `2`, but your sample output says you want `1`, then `2`, and `3`.
5. `waitpid()` is better than `wait()`, here, since you want to wait on a specific process. Similarly, your `sleep()` call is superfluous when you use this.
6. While it's not necessary to `close()` your pipes here just before you exit, it's sometimes helpful to do so, again because it can bring errors to your attention if you've done something wrong.
7. Your `if (pid[j] > 0)` check is unnecessary, since you already terminate if `fork()` fails or if it's `0`, so you already know it'll be greater than `0` by the time you get here.
8. You don't need the `status` variable to retrieve the exit status of your process if you're not going to use it - you can just pass `NULL` to `wait()` or `waitpid()`.
9. Minor point, but you don't need to use a different variable name (i.e. `j`) for your second `for` loop, since the scope of `i` in your first `for` loop is limited to that loop. If you're going to use `i` as the generic name for your loop counters, you might as well use it everywhere you can.
10. `return EXIT_FAILURE` is better than `return -1`, and that value will be converted to `255` when you retrieve the exit status anyway.
11. It's very unlikely to be a problem in reality, but `fork()` returns type `pid_t`, not type `int`, so it's better to make `pid` an array of that type.

Here's some revised code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd[3][2];
    pid_t pid[3];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        if ( pipe(fd[i]) == -1 ) {
            perror("pipe() failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if ( (pid[i] = fork()) == -1 ) {
            perror("fork() failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else if ( pid[i] == 0 ) {
            if ( close(fd[i][0]) == -1 ) {
                perror("close() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            char arr[100];
            sprintf(arr, "%d", i + 1);

            if ( write(fd[i][1], arr, 1) == -1 ) {
                perror("write() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            if ( close(fd[i][1]) == -1 ) {
                perror("close() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else {
            if ( close(fd[i][1]) == -1 ) {
                perror("close() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        if ( waitpid(pid[i], NULL, 0) == -1 ) {
            perror("waitpid() failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        char out[100] = {0};
        if ( read(fd[i][0], out, 99) == -1 ) {
            perror("read() failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("%s\nI am the parent\n", out);

        if ( close(fd[i][0]) == -1 ) {
            perror("close() failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./pipe
1
I am the parent
2
I am the parent
3
I am the parent
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```